# Include Javascript/CSS via https?

Tags: javascript, css, ssl, https

I'm currently facing the problem that I want to serve **static content via a subdomain** `static.mydomain.tld` but my **SSL certificate is only valid for my main domain** `mydomain.tld`

Should I include my javascript, css and images over a secure connection when https is used or can I still use `http://static.mydomain.tld`.

I would *change my javascript* so that AJAX requests will *use https* over the main domain.

Or shouldn't I use the subdomain and include the files from the main domain?

(I was thinking about using a subdomain because I read that static content should be served from a domain that doesn't set cookies)

Thank you!

Comment: "I read that static content should be served from a domain that doesn't set cookies". Where did you read that? If it's for improving usage of HTTP proxy servers, it doesn't really matter, since they won't see the content of the HTTPS connection anyway.

Comment: Several speed test told me to do this, including YSlow from Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I include my javascript, css and images over a secure connection when https is used

Yes. Otherwise it is subject to interception and modification. Replaced images can present users with false data. Replaced JS and CSS (since CSS can embed JS) can execute scripts and leak data from the secure environment.

> shouldn't I use the subdomain and include the files from the main domain?

That is an option.

You can also get another SSL cert for the other host name.